# Cannot read property 'Image' of undefined error on Nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I was Trying to make a shopping cart. i was making admin panel in which i need to submit the image for adding product. After creating the Form

```html
       <section>
      <div class="container mt-4">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2 class="text-cnter">Add Product</h2>

            <form action="/admin/add-product" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

              <label for="">Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="Name" class="form-control">

              <label for="">Category</label>
              <input type="text" name="Category" class="form-control">

              <label for="">Price</label>
              <input type="text" name="Price" class="form-control">

              <label for="">Description</label>
              <input type="text" name="Description" class="form-control">

              <label for="">Image</label>
              <input type="file" class="form-control">

              <button class="btn btn-success mt-4" type="submit">Submit </button>

            </form>

          </div>


        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

In admin.js file ( where router of admin )

```js
  

router.get('/add-products',function(req,res){
  res.render('admin/add-products')
});

// router.post('/add-product',function (req,res) {
//   console.log('Got it')
// });

router.post( "/add-product", function( req, res ) {

   console.log(req.body)
   console.log(req.file.Image)
  

});

module.exports = router;
```

app.js file

```js
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var hbs = require('express-handlebars');
var fileupload =require('express-fileupload');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var userRouter = require('./routes/user');
var adminRouter = require('./routes/admin');
const {allowInsecurePrototypeAccess} = require('@handlebars/allow-prototype-access')
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');

var multipartMiddleware = multipart();


var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

//Layout Directory Set
app.engine('hbs',hbs.engine({ extname:'hbs' , defaultLayout:'layout',layoutsDir:__dirname+'/views/layout/',partialsDir:__dirname+'/views/partials'}));

app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine({
  handlebars: allowInsecurePrototypeAccess(hbs)
}));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(fileupload());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use('/', userRouter);
app.use('/admin', adminRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

after running with nodemon giving submit button shows

Cannot read property 'Image' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Image' of undefined

Btw i was just started on nodejs .Thats why i dont know more about it.

Comment: req.file doesn't exist... You need to find out how to handle files (I don't know that). Plus you want to make some kind of response at the end of router.post( "/add-product")  or the request will hang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check this line in your admin.js file:
`console.log(req.file.Image)`

Based on the error message `req.file`is `undefined` and therefor it can't read `Image`.

The reason is, that express needs extra middleware to correctly handle multipart/form-data. Check out [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer). This should help you getting all the parts of your form including the file(s).

Also be aware that your file input does not have a same. So you definitely can't find it with `Image`.

Comment: I had installed multer and defined it as in the github. Also done with this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70543062/14378335

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `req.file` is undefined, so it can't read the property `Image` of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

try changing this. first provide a name to your input file

```
 <label for="">Image</label>
 <input type="file" name = "img" class="form-control">
```

try getting the file then using

```
router.post( "/add-product", function( req, res ) {

console.log(req.body)
console.log(req.files.img)


});
```